# UML редактор для C#?

Tags: c#, uml

В VisualStudio есть вполне рабочий редактор UML. В экспресс выпуске он исключен, но мне он больше подходит по некоторым причинам. Также хочется разрабатывать проект вне дома (на работе), где студия не доступна, а также не доступен флеш и интернет. Какой редактор (Portable) можете посоветовать скачать и почему?

Comment: благо, что уже не работаю на этой работе)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне нравится [Software Ideas Modeler](http://www.softwareideas.net/).

А [отсюда](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) вы сможете подобрать редактор, наиболее подходящий под ваши нужды/вкусы.

Comment: спасибо, очень хороший редактор, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю как Вам, но мне нравится [Visio 2010](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3056633)

На Celeron D, 2gb очень хорошо подошла. Сама прога работает быстро и без глюков
Инсталяция тоже быстро пройшла на слабом компе

Схема модели UML, Схема модели БД, Структура программы, Схема модели потоков данных,
COM и OLE, Карта сайта, Корпоративное приложение и т д

Рекомендую!

Comment: А как насчет генерации кода, реверсинжениринга, экспорта, легкости изменения методов и свойств? На Visio 2003 это очень слабо сделано, как там дело обстоит с 2010 версией? тем более весит он солидно, его надо устанавливать, стоит ли он того?

Comment: Неужели я ошибался, и волшебная палочка существует? (а генерация кода -- мерзость ещё та)

Comment: на счет генерации кода - я не в курсе, так как мало реального опыта. Но хочется верить, что эта палочка будет волшебной, а не палкой в колёса)

Comment: Скорее всего это волшебная палочка в колёса.

Answer (score 1):

Ну из векторных редакторов найти что-то равноценное xfig -- задача невыполнимая. По крайней мере из лёгких. Из более тяжёлых -- не считается (dia, например -- тоже из более тяжёлых, хотя зачастую xfig'у уступает)

Comment: чуть позже протестирую xfig, но мне очень понравился предложенный выше  Software Ideas Modeler. ему предварительно 8 баллов.

Comment: xfig требует некоторого времени, чтобы понять его преимущества (лёгкость и скорость редактирования). Ну а множество форматов -- от родного ему transfig'а (xfig требует transfig)

Comment: Не знаю, как насчет преимуществ, но недостатков у него много: 1)установка неудобная, нужна компиляция,2)старая (2007 года),3)это простой векторный редактор, к UML имеет слабое отношение

Comment: Ну учитывая то, что гуры рекомендовали uml рисовать вообще в MS Word...

Comment: alexlz, ты пробовал Software Ideas Modeller? Просмотрел все редакторы, хочу отметить его как ответ на вопрос. Единственный недостаток - отрисовка не через видеокарту (заметно). Но лучше по UML для C# в условиях переносимости и размеров, плюс функций, да и рисует красиво, бесплатен - наверно нет.

Comment: Это провокационный вопрос. Я с uml вообще не очень-то. А про xfig написал только потому, что видел в нём библиотеку шаблонов uml